# I can't determine why Javascript is apparently stopping my code when I use 'after' method

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to process some attributes in order to process HTML templates using Javascript. The problem I have is about two attributes I'm trying to process in this loop: 'repeat' and 'iterate'. This snippet code below just identify what attribute is going to be processed. I suppressed part of the code in order to make the problem visualization easier.

```
        // Loop of the attributes
        Array.from(obj.attributes).forEach((attr) => {
            let vars = this.vars.load()
            let snake_name = attr.name
            let action_name = this.util.toCamel(snake_name)
            // Replacing vars on attribute values
            let params = attr.value
            params = this.action.replaceVarsOnStr(params, vars)
            // looking for special attributes
            try {

                if(action_name == "repeat"){
                    console.log("REPEATING...: " + obj.id )
```

//                        // TODO Check for variables in id first
let repeat = obj.getAttribute("repeat")
console.log("REPEAT VALUE: " + repeat)
if(repeat.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
this.action.repeat(obj, obj, repeat)
}
obj.removeAttribute("repeat")
}

```
                else if(action_name == "iterate"){
                    console.log("ITERATING...: " + obj.id)
                    obj.removeAttribute("iterate")
                }

            }
            catch(e) {
                console.error("Can't parse attribute '"+ snake_name +"'! Reason: " + e)
            }
        })
```

The 'repeat' on 'if' is used to call a homonymous method in other class which executes the object repeating and is the source of the problem. The code below is the code of 'repeat' method I've noticed before. At below the code of method 'repeat' calls the method 'after' applied to the clone objects in order to place it in the right position.

```
    repeat(obj, target, times, position='after', modify_original_id=true) {
        /* Repeats an element n times positioning the clones before or after a target element. */
        if( typeof(times) == "integer" || times.match(/^[0-9]+$/) ) {
            times = parseInt(times)
            try {
                let vars = this.vars.load()
                // Assuming target as obj if it's not defined
                if(target === undefined || target == null) target = obj;
                // Getting parent
                for(var t = times; t > 1; t--) {
                    var clone = obj.cloneNode(true)
                    clone.id = clone.id + '_' + t
                    clone.removeAttribute('repeat')
                    // #####################################
                    target.after(clone) // THE PROBLEMATIC METHOD 'after'
                    // #####################################
                }
                obj.id = obj.id + '_1'
                // Modifying original ids if suffix is set as _\d+. If it's not, set modify_original_id as false
                if(obj.id === null || obj.id === undefined || obj.id === "")
                if(modify_original_id) obj.id += '_1';
                // Applying traverse to the original obj
                if(obj.childNodes !== undefined) this._traverse_repeat(obj, t);
                // Removing the 'repeat' tag from original object
                obj.removeAttribute('repeat')
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.error("Error on repeat! Reason: " + e)
            }
         }
         else {
            console.log("times is not numeric")
         }
    }
```

Debugging the code, I figure out this code works well. Because the objects are being repeated after all. The problem is(and this is weird), the loop in the previous code simply doesn't continue to the next attribute. Why?

```
Array.from(obj.attributes).forEach((attr) => { ...
```

PS: Please, only vanilla Javascript, all right? Thanks!

Comment: I've already tried to put the object to repeat in an Array to process later. But the result is the same. It's like everything in the loop disappear when `after` method is called.

Comment: Are you removing stuff from obj.attributes while you are iterating it?  Potential problem right there.

Comment: @James `Array.from()` makes a copy, so they're not iterating over the same array that they're removing from.

Comment: `t > 1` should be `t > 0`. You're not repeating enough times.

Comment: You're missing the code block after `if(obj.id === null || obj.id === undefined || obj.id === "")`. So it's executing the next `if` statement when one of these conditions is true.

Comment: Have you tried using the single-stepper in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Does this problem only happen when `obj == target`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.